# How to match strings, ignoring certain characters

Tags: ruby, string

I have to match pairs of strings, ignoring spaces `" "` and hyphens `"-"`. I want to regard the following pairs as identical.

- `"2,3 chloro benzene"` and `"2,3 chlorobenzene"`
- `"4'3',2-dinitrotoluene"` and `"4'3',2-di nitro toluene"`

Due to the spaces, I cannot match them. How can I do that? I am not sure how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: *Due to spaces, I cannot match them* - is this your explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete) to delete unwanted chars and normalize the two strings before comparing them, as shown below:

```
s1 = "2,3 chloro-benzene"
s2 = "2,3 chlorobenzene"

s1.delete(" -") == s2.delete(" -")
#=> true
```